# Program with PDFBox does not run on eclipse, but runs on command line

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, pdfbox, gradle-eclipse

I am having a problem running a program which has Apache's pdfbox in the classpath.

When I run the application through eclipse, it just terminates before running any command.

A simple Hello world (which does not even use pdfbox) does not work.

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
}
```

I just added one dependency via gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.8';
}
```

This is enough for the program not to run. On eclipse's Error log there is nothing.

HOWEVER, if I run it through command line, it works just fine. Does anyone knows what is happening?

> Obs.: I am using eclipse Oxygen 1a and Java JDK 8u144, all x86.

Comment: The *Error Log* view shows unexpected errors of the Eclipse IDE. You have to look into the *Problems* view for errors that keep your project from being built.

Comment: Hmmm...Problems View is empty as well.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: In eclipse: Package explorer, right click on TestMain.java > Run As... > Java Application; Command-line: java -cp "<path containing pdfbox and eclipse-compiled classes>" TestMain

Comment: Delete the run configuration and retry. If the problem persists, check the Java build path of the run configuration. Consider to update your Eclipse IDE to Oxygen.1 (especially Gradle support has been improved in the last months).

Comment: Updated to Eclipse Oxygen and it is still not working..

Comment: I don't see how that's related to pdfbox. You have added a reference to the jar and that's about it. You are not using pdfbox in your `TestMain` class. Does it run if you remove the `pdfbox` dependency?

Comment: @Raf , yes, it runs without pdfbox. Actually it seems more gradle-related, because if I do not use gradle (just add files manually) or use maven, it works.

Comment: In that case, maybe you should update your question to include the entire `build.gradle` just in case somebody spot an issue with it and help you fix it.

Comment: How did you import your project into eclipse? Are you using the buildship IDE plugin? Or did you `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` in your gradle build and generate the `.classpath` and `.project` files from command line? If neither of these then your eclipse classpath will not match the gradle classpath